# iOS spritekit nodes stutter when transitioning from scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm developing a game in iOS Spritekit using Objective C. I created a menu view in viewController and from that I'm calling a gameScene. In gameScene I uses five different nodes which has to released one by one randomly from the top of the screen. Each of those five nodes have 4 different images so it is stored in atlas. If the node moves to the bottom of the screen I change the image in the node and release from the top of the screen.

I'm releasing the node using the following code

```
self.wait = [SKAction waitForDuration: 1.0];
self.run = [SKAction runBlock:^{
if ([nodesArray count] > 0) {
   //select the node to release randomly and remove it from array
}
}];
self.seq = [SKAction sequence: @[self.wait, self.run]];
```

Those five nodes are stored in an array called nodesArray.

Code for selecting the random node :

```
int i = arc4random() %[nodesArray count];
SKSpriteNode *mynode = nodesArray[i];
```

For removing the node in array :

```
[nodesArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
```

After for setting the position :

```
mynode.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
```

and for velocity :

```
mynode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx,dy)
```

And finally add the node to scene :

```
[self addChild: mynode];
```

Repeat these steps until the array count is 0.

Now my problem is that I noticed a stutter when the nodes are released from the array. I don't know why these stutter are occurs as it's random, these predominantly occurs when the scene is restarted or If I come from another scene to game scene. When I come directly to GameScene without any intermediate scene with just a Launchscreen.xib  , there is no stutter.

For restarting the scene I call the scene by the following code

```
GameScene *firstScene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
[self.view presentScene:firstScene transition:[SKTransition fadeWithDuration:1.0]]
```

PS. I also tried implementing Menu as a scene and returning to game scene, nevertheless it too causes random stutter in the game scene irrespective of whether I remove the Node's & Actions before I leave the Game Scene.

Already added a log statement to know how many nodes are available in array.

```
NSLog(@"Nodes Count is %lu and Random Number is %lu",(unsigned long)[nodesArray count],(unsigned long)i);
```

After removing the node, the array count will be one less than normal count.

```
NSLog(@"Nodes Count is %lu",(unsigned long)[nodesArray count]);
```

After removing all nodes, the method won't call so it wouldn't print any log inside this method.

Log Output :

2014-12-04 11:17:31.171 newGame[633:21010] Nodes Count is 5 and Random Number is 2

Now the second node in the array will be called. After removing the second node in array the array count will be shown in the next log.

2014-12-04 11:17:31.171 newGame[633:21010] Nodes Count after removal of node : 4

This is the bug which is stopping me from releasing the game, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How large is the array? What else are you doing at this point in time? Have you tried Instruments to measure where the lag is coming from?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D The array consists of those five nodes. I'm selecting 1 node randomly from the array and remove that node from array. Then I'm setting the position and velocity to the node and adding it to the scene. The stutter occurs only we call the gameScene again after going to help scene or main scene, so I removed those scenes and implemented views instead but still stutter occurs when I restart the game scene. I used instruments profiling extensively for Time,memory, even open GL driver and couldn't find anything out of ordinary.

Comment: Try rebooting the device to ensure there aren't any background tasks interfering.

Comment: Are you doing this on the simulator or an actual device?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Yes I tried restarting and even factory resetting the iPhone. Guess all doors are closed now, do you think changing to implemented the Game scene using story board or. sks will help ? Also if that doesn't help, only other options I can think of is changing the Game Scene implementation from Sprite kit to cocos2d-swift (objective C)  or do you think changing to Swift will help in anyways?

Comment: @MobileBen I'm doing this on the device iPhone 5c.

Comment: It would probably be useful to show more code. Your code for actually selecting the random node (code you put a comment in for) as well as the code and an explanation of what calls the code the code to do the removal. You may want to add a println to see how many times the code is called as well as to time the removal process. Depending. On how you randomly select, that could cause the problem.

Comment: @MobileBen I have updated the code with what you've asked.Let me know if you can find something amiss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do these nodes have textures and how large are they? One possibility is that they are large and you are experiencing the overhead of texture loading, depending on how you are initializing your assets.

Comment: @MobileBen Yes all the nodes are having textures and those textures are stored in atlas. The atlas are created with the help of Texture packer. The compressed texture size is 431kb. I initialized the atlas at the beginning itself. But irrespective of Size or  compression, the stutter still occurs. But on game restarts there are no stutters for a while.  I have no experience with cocos2d, should I port my game to cocos2d and check? I don't have much time tough.

Comment: When you say irrespective of size, what happens if the atlas in its entirety was say 64x64 (making it small). Typically, you should preload your textures while you're doing something like showing an activity indicator. Once your textures are loaded, then you do stuff. I've noticed most people posting do not do this. I'm not sure this is your problem but am just guessing if you are seeing inconsistency. Although I suppose in that case, since you have only one texture, it would only stutter once perhaps. Each scene change has new texture(s)?

Comment: @MobileBen I'm using four different images for each of those five nodes. I converted those textures into atlas using Texture Packer. For preloading textures we use [SKTexture preloadTextures: withCompletionHandler:] but how to preload those Texture Packer atlas. I just import the .h file created from the Texture Packer in gameScene to use the texture.

Comment: Is your menuView UIKit and still active when the gameScene is active? Also, have you tried a test of removing some of the "moving parts". For example, instead of randomly picking one, use a fixed order you always use (just for testing). Or instead of replacing the node when it reaches the bottom, keep the node the same and release it from the top. What this is doing it trying to isolate causality. In addition, you probably need to show more of your code. Understood you put some snippets in, but it is difficult to tell how they fit together or what else is "missing".

Comment: @MobileBen These days I tried with different combinations in different engines.In spritekit, 1 node dropping from top and it stutter.I removed everything in Update method and Collision method and just simply drop the node still no change. In Cocos-2D-Obj C using Sprite Builder - 1 node, stutter occurs = or > sprite kit.
In Unity - 1 node drop from top of the scene. Here the movement looks better not as good as sprite-kit when stutter does not occur. Interestingly stutter does not occur in iPad-Air with small textures. iPad only game or Unity free are my only option,what you think ?

Comment: Hmm, hearing what you have written makes me think that what possibly is happening is that when the scene transitions, the time intervals being applied to the physics and potentially to update are having longer delays than expected, which can affect some things. As an experiment can you try these things? In the scene's didMoveToView, have a flag set which will indicate you should print out delta time information for didSimulatePhysicsForScen and update:forScene. Also add a timer that fires off in say 5 seconds which will turn of that flag to output.

Comment: In addition, try the added permutation of starting off with no moving nodes. When the timer fires after the 5 seconds, have the nodes animate and see if they are "smooth". What will be interesting to see is if you get relatively smooth delta time or choppy values.